# Renaming files using regex

Tags: regular-expression, rename, file-management

I have a number of files in a folder on a Linux machine with the following names:

```
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35
```

I would like to use regex in order to rename with the .inp extension

I tried

```
mv * *.inp
mv: target '*.inp' is not a directory
```

which provided an error. I also tried using the regex [123][12345] instead of the *.

So, I understand that mv is used to move files around. I also got the idea that perhaps I could use `./*.inp`  to force mv to write in the same folder but it failed. So, apart from not understading correctly how `mv` works, how would I proceed to have have this done with `mv`?

Comment: What Linux are you using? Do you have th `perl-rename` (might be called `rename` or `prename`) command?

Comment: Hello! I am using the following:

 LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Release:        7.9.2009
Codename:       Core

And yes, I have perl rename.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with your command is that the `mv` command only can move/rename a single file (when given exactly two command line arguments), or move a bunch of files to a single destination directory (more than two command line arguments).

In your case, you use the expansion of `* *.inp` as the arguments, and this is going to expand to all the visible filenames in the current directory, followed by the names that matches `*.inp`.  Assuming that this expands to more than two names, then the last argument needs to be the name of a directory for the command to be a valid `mv` command, or you'll get a "is not a directory" error.

In this case, we instead want to use `mv` with two arguments at a time, and for that we need to use a shell loop:

```bsh
for name in [123][1-5]; do
    mv "$name" "$name.inp"
done
```

This loops over all names that matches (a variant of) the filename globbing pattern that you mentioned (note, this is not a regular expression).  In the loop body, the current name will be stored in the `name` variable, and the `mv` simply renames the file by adding `.inp` at the end of the name.

This does not prevent `mv` from overwriting existing files in the case where there might be a name collision.  For that, assuming you use GNU `mv`, you may want to use `mv` with its `--no-clobber` (or `-n`) option, or possibly with its `--backup` (or `-b`) option.

Or, you could do an explicit check for the existence of the destination name and skip the current file if it exists (which would also avoid moving files into exiting directories if you happened to have a directory with the same name as the destination name):

```bsh
for name in [123][1-5]; do
    [ -e "$name.inp" ] || [ -L "$name.inp" ] && continue
    mv "$name" "$name.inp"
done
```

Using GNU `mv` with `--no-target-directory` (or `-T`) in combination with either `-n` or `-b` would avoid overwriting existing files (or back them up, with `-b`) and also avoid moving the files into a subdirectory that happened to have the same name as the destination name.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `perl-rename` tool:

```bsh
rename -n 's/$/.inp/' [0-9][0-9]
```

(or alternatively, use `'$_ .= ".inp"'` to append `.inp`, should be faster because no regex needs to be evaluated.)

Remove the `-n` if you're happy with the output.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`'s batch-renaming `zmv` function:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '[1-3][1-5]' '$f.inp'
```

The advantage over some of the other solutions mentioned here:

- it will run some sanity checks first. For instance, if that could cause any data loss, it would abort the command before doing *any* renaming.
- `[1-5]` is the same as `[12345]` in `zsh`. In `bash` and in the most common locales and on GNU systems, `[1-5]` would be more like `[12345١٢٣٤۱۲۳۴߁߂߃߄१२३४১২৩৪੧੨੩੪૧૨૩૪୧୨୩୪௧௨௩௪౧౨౩౪౹౺౻౼౽౾೧೨೩೪൧൨൩൪෧෨෩෪๑๒๓๔໑໒໓໔༡༢༣༤༪༫༬༭၁၂၃၄႑႒႓႔፩፪፫፬១២៣៤៱៲៳៴᠑᠒᠓᠔᥇᥈᥉᥊᧑᧒᧓᧔᧚᪁᪂᪃᪄᪑᪒᪓᪔᭑᭒᭓᭔᮱᮲᮳᮴᱁᱂᱃᱄᱑᱒᱓᱔⁴₁₂₃₄⅐⅑⅒⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅛⅜⅟①②③④⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳⑴⑵⑶⑷⑽⑾⑿⒀⒁⒂⒃⒄⒅⒆⒇⒈⒉⒊⒋⒑⒒⒓⒔⒕⒖⒗⒘⒙⒚⒛⓫⓬⓭⓮⓯⓰⓱⓲⓳⓴⓵⓶⓷⓸⓾❶❷❸❹❿➀➁➂➃➉➊➋➌➍➓〡〢〣〤㉈㉉㉊㉋㉑㉒㉓㉔㉕㉖㉗㉘㉙㉚㉛㉜㉝㉞㉟㊱㊲㊳㊴㊵㊶㊷㊸㊹㊺㊻㊼㊽㊾㋀㋁㋂㋃㋉㋊㋋㍙㍚㍛㍜㍢㍣㍤㍥㍦㍧㍨㍩㍪㍫㍬㍭㍮㍯㍰㏠㏡㏢㏣㏩㏪㏫㏬㏭㏮㏯㏰㏱㏲㏳㏴㏵㏶㏷㏸㏹㏺㏻㏼㏽㏾꘡꘢꘣꘤꣑꣒꣓꣔꤁꤂꤃꤄꧑꧒꧓꧔꧱꧲꧳꧴꩑꩒꩓꩔꯱꯲꯳꯴１２３４]`
- it will not rename a file called literally `[1-3][1-5]` if there's no file that match that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (in bash):

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in !(*.*); do mv -v "$f" "$f.inp"; done
```

With the `extglob` option enabled (this is what `shopt -s extglob` does), `!(*.*)` finds all files without an extension. If you want to find other files, that would need to change.

If you really need regular expressions, another way would be:

```
for f in $(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -regex '\.\/[123][12345]'); do mv -v "$f" "$f.inp"; done
```

@pLum0 says find should not be used in for loop. So this is also possible:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -regex '\.\/[123][12345]' -exec mv -v "{}" "{}.inp" \;
```

Comment: What shell have you written this for? You also don't point out what the issue is with the user's command.

Comment: This is in bash.

Comment: Then you probably also need `shopt -s extglob`, right? And possibly `nullglob` too?

Comment: You should not loop over `find` output... `find` has `-exec`.

Comment: @pLumo you're right, of course, but that wouldn't be a problem in this specific case since the `find` results are limited to names matching `\.\/[123][12345]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mmv command if available for your distro.

See for example http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mmv.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Using [rnr](https://github.com/ismaelgv/rnr) the command would be:

```
rnr -f '([0-9][0-9])' '${1}.inp' *
```

`rnr` has the benefit of being able to [undo](https://github.com/ismaelgv/rnr#undoredo-operations-using-dump-file) the command.